# Verilog - Delay in implementation of SPI master slave interface

Tags: verilog, spi, master-slave

My code for top module (spi master slave):

```
module top(en,en_s,sclk,data_rg,tr_rg,rst,s_rst,ss_bar,rcv_rg,m_data_rg);
input [7:0] data_rg,tr_rg;
input en,en_s,sclk,rst,s_rst,ss_bar;
output [7:0] rcv_rg,m_data_rg;
ms m1(.en(en),.data_rg(data_rg),.sclk(sclk),.rst(rst),.miso(miso),.mosi(mosi),.ss_bar(ss_bar),.rcv_rg(rcv_rg));
slv m2(.en_s(en_s),.tr_rg(tr_rg),.ss_bar(ss_bar),.sclk(sclk),.s_rst(s_rst),.mosi(mosi),.miso(miso),.m_data_rg(m_data_rg));
initial
$display ("Transmitter data %d, %d",data_rg,tr_rg );
endmodule
```

In the above code, master module gets executed first and then slave is executed. Right now, I'm facing a delay in interfacing. It should be full duplex.

architecture of spi master slave:
[image: Snap1]

timing diagram of master slave
[image: Snap2]

Comment: Modules can not be instantiated after a delay. Instantiating module means adding hardware to your board. This hardware acts in a parallel fashion in real world scenario. So, where is it exactly where you want to add delay? Is it in the instantiation (which is not possible) or in the modules itself (which can be done by using some counters)?

Comment: i do not want to add delay ,..... i want that ,what is the reason behind master receives data of slave(45) in 9 clk pulse where slave receives  data of master(93) in only 8 pulse? where

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to provide the source for your ms and slv modules.  From what you have provided above, I can see that there appears to be something like a wire assignment in the slave for shf_rg[7:0] and it appears registered shft_reg[7:0] in the master unit.

something like

```
//slave code
reg [7:0] last_sft_reg;
wire shf_reg[7:0];  // Notice not a register
always (posedge clk)
 begin
      last_sft_reg <= shf_reg;
 end

 assign shf_reg = {last_sft_reg[6:0],mosi};  // shf_reg updates immediately 
                                             // when mosi changes

// master code
reg [7:0] shft_reg;
always (posedge clk or posedge reset)
 begin 
 if (reset)
   shft_reg <= 'h0;
 else
   shft_reg <= {shft_reg[6:0],miso};
 end
```

I want you to consider the following.  You may actually be processing the content in 8 clocks overall, with 1 clock latency in the master.  In otherwords, if you were doing back to back transactions, the rate of the slave and the master may be the same, but if you lined up the transactions, you would always see the master starting one clock later and thus finishing one clock later.  To demonstrate, if you do 100 transactions, does the master still only finish one clock behind the slave?  If so, it's probably not an issue.